# How to give condition for null values of multi select parameter in Ireport?

Tags: null, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am developing a report using [iReport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports#Third-party_tools) where I want to add a condition for null values. It's working with single select option as:

```
(city=$P{p_city} or $P{p_city} is null)
```

It means here if we do not pass any value for the city parameter, the report will work, but this is not working in case of a multiselect option. We have to choose a "Collection" value expression in iReport when we create a parameter:

```
($X{IN, country,p_country} or $P{p_country} is null)
```

I have created two input controls in [JasperReports Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports#Jaspersoft) to run this report. One is a single select, "Select City" and the other is a multi select, "Select country", and the report is running without passing a value for the "Select city" parameter, but for the "select country" parameter, we must pass the value, because "Select country" is multi select and a Collection type parameter and you can not add null condition in a query as for the city parameter.

How we can modify the [JRXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports#JRXML) query?

Comment: The iReport is just a GUI designer for report's template constructing. Is your question is really about a GUI designer? Do you want to modify the `query` expression in your `jrxml` file?

Comment: Thanks but i did not get any helpful answer.If i get any right answer i will accept.

Comment: yes i want to change the query rxpression in jrxml file

Comment: It is quite easy. Can you post (in your question) the query to modify?

Comment: And where is the original query (that need to be modified)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $X feature handles this automatically. In your case you have this in your query:

```
$X{IN, country, p_country}
```

That gets converted to `1 = 1` in the case where your Collection is null. So there is no reason to add `$P{p_country} is null` into the query.

Comment: But in the case of collection parameter $X{IN,country,p_country} you must have to give at least one input value in Jasper server or Ireport. you can not run report without giving input value for collection type parameters but you can run report without passing input control in case of this parameter (city=$P{p_city} or $P{p_city} is null).

Comment: I commonly give 0 input values for a collection parameter. What makes you think that you cannot?

Answer (score 1):

When the value of Collection parameter is NULL then to hide all the data output is done by bellow 
print when expression on table component.

```
P{Collection_Parameter_Name}.size()>0
```

#### notes:

1. Collection parameter takes the syntax `$X{IN,filed_Name,param_Name}` in SQL query but here we have to take it
   as `$P{Collection_parameter_Name}`
2. If you print parameter on the report you will get different sizes of the collection parameter (Number of selected values in collection drop down)

Answer (score 0):

You could put your condition like this
 city IN ($P!{p_city})

Then you could call by the url with:

```
http://ip:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=/reports/reports&reportUnit=/reports/reports/rptReporte&j_username=jasperreportadmin&j_password=jasperreportadmin&p_city='city1','city2'
```