# problems in Multi Select query

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to use a Multi select query in order to populate few date fields.
I have an input control 'date_id' which selects the required dates. Its a simple select statement

```
select distinct date_id from <table>.
```

My date_id s are of type **DATE**

I have created a parameter date_id.
Since I have to use `$X{IN,date_id,$P{date_id}}` syntax, i.e, `$X{IN,<field_name>,<parameter_name>}` syntax, I have my parameter **date_id** of type **java.util.collections**

In doing so, I have modified the input control query also.
So my final input control query is

```
select distinct CAST(date_id AS CHAR) as date_id  from <table>
```

But there is a mismatch.
The error says, parameter type not supported in the query.
I referred to a lot of SO [Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782107/how-to-give-condition-for-null-values-of-multi-select-parameter-in-ireport) etc, but it didn't help.
Can any one let me know the mistake I am committing here?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you use the ${} on your input as they are the same name this might get confusing but i think it should look like `$X{IN,date_id,date_id}`  I would rename my Pram. toy something like In_Date_id to make it easier to read  `$X{IN,date_id, In_date_id}`

Comment: Thank you @Mnoland . Your explanation indeed helped me. Instead of dates, I tried with normal string and it worked fine.I am trying to look around how to handle dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I added a cast to the field name in $X syntax and removed $P{} syntax from the parameter, it worked i.e,

`SELECT * FROM <Your Table> where $X{IN,CAST(date_id AS CHAR),date_id}`

Hope this helps someone facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving it would be to filter the non-selected items out using a filter expression in the report like this:

```
<filterExpression><![CDATA[$P{date_id}.contains($F{date_id})]]></filterExpression>
```